# SQL Error: ORA-02270: no matching unique or primary key for this column-list [ask]

Tags: database, oracle

Is it possible to make a column not primary key, to be foreign key in other table? for example :

-- for master table

```
create table identity(
 id int not null,
 name_identity varchar2(100),
 primary key(id)
);
```

--for foreign key

```
create table class(
 class_id int,
 name_identity varchar2(100),
 primary key(class_id),
 foreign key(name_identity) references identity(name_identity)
);
```

Is it possible to make name_identity as foreign key?

Comment: foreign key should be unique. it can be null-able but uniqueness is necessary. if name_identity in master table is unique, you can do what you asked for.

Answer (score 1):

Foreign key doesn't rely on column, it's rely on unique key instead. Primary key is a special case of unique key so it can be used as well.

In your case you should use something like `name_identity varchar2(100) unique` and you'll can use it in foreign key after that.